# Using boost multiprecision with Rcpp on Windows

Tags: r, boost, rcpp

I'm trying to compile and use the following code (which I have seen on SO):

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <boost/multiprecision/float128.hpp>

namespace mp = boost::multiprecision;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::string mexp(double mx)
{
  mp::float128 x(mx);
  mp::float128 res = mp::exp(x);
  return res.convert_to<std::string>();
}
```

Before compiling, I have to do `Sys.setenv("PKG_LIBS" = "-lquadmath")` otherwise the compilation does not work. 
Then the compilation runs fine, but when I type `mexp(1)` in R, the R session totally crashes. Am I missing something ? The session crashes in RStudio as well as in the classical R gui.

PS: I am under Windows and I get the crash with R-3.3.3 as well as R-3.4.1.

#### Edit:

Just tried on Linux with R-3.4.1 and this works fine. I even don't need to do `Sys.setenv("PKG_LIBS" = "-lquadmath")`.

Comment: Are you using RStudio? If so, you need to be on RStudio v1.1 Preview

Comment: Yes, I'm using RStudio. Why do I need another version ?

Comment: RStudio prior to v1.1 Preview has an interaction with boost when code being used requires _linking_. This issue was corrected when boost was moved to its own namespace in RStudio. This is what is causing your _R_ session in _RStudio_ to crash.

Comment: R by default only has 64 bit double types.  Going beyond requires extra code, which may require linking.  I would think the Boost multiprecision documentation has something to say about it.

Comment: Re your edit, try `grep quadmath /etc/R/Makeconf` (or point at whereever `Makeconf` lives on your Linux) and discover that `-lquadmath` is a default.  Welcome to OS-dependent code, ie the headaches of portability.

Comment: And, as @coatless reminds us, you _must switch to newer RStudio builds_ to avoid interactions with Boost as the RStudio binary itself also depends on Boost---and different versions bite.

Comment: Ok thank you. I'll try to upgrade RStudio later.

Comment: Of course, if you run the code outside of RStudio you avoid that issue and can concentrate on whether or not your OS had quadmath.

Comment: I've just tried in the classical Rgui and this crashes the session as well. This is really a crash of the R session, not the RStudio session (cc @DirkEddelbuettel)

Comment: So this is not a duplicate, I think.

Comment: I compiles and runs for me on Linux, without crashing.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Me too, no problem on Linux (I can even replace `mp::exp(x)` with `boost::math::erf(x)` and this works, while this causes other problems under Windows).

Comment: I confirm this crashes the new RStudio as well. @coatless could you remove your vote for closing ? This is not a duplicate.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is the gcc compiler (4.9.3) that ships with _Rtools_ has some incompatibility with `float128` as the [boost docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/floats.html) indicate the only dependency is libquadmath.

Comment: Yeah, looks like it is an issue with the compiler since `mp::float128` initializes properly; however, computations with `mp::exp()` cause the session breakage.

Comment: Thanks for your investigations @coatless. That's sad, I have implemented an algorithm with float128 (on Linux) and this is really awesome.

Comment: @nrussell any thoughts on this?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel it works with g++ 6.2.0 !!

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Glad to hear :)